# Using XSLT to transform XML to HTML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml file that consists of nesting of certain elements except the first one. The xml looks like this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--This file represents the results of running a test suite-->
<test-results name="value" total="5" errors="0" failures="5" not-run="0" inconclusive="0" ignored="0" skipped="0" invalid="0" date="2014-07-18" time="17:09:15">
  <environment nunit-version="2.6.3.13283" clr-version="2.0.50727.5420" os-version="Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1" platform="Win32NT" cwd="value" machine-name="value" user="value" user-domain="value" />
  <culture-info current-culture="en-US" current-uiculture="en-US" />
  <test-suite type="Assembly" name="value" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="1.863" asserts="0">
    <results>
      <test-suite type="Namespace" name="value" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="1.849" asserts="0">
        <results>
          <test-suite type="Namespace" name="value" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="1.848" asserts="0">
            <results>
              <test-suite type="Namespace" name="value" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="1.848" asserts="0">
                <results>
                  <test-suite type="Namespace" name="Tests" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="1.848" asserts="0">
                    <results>
                      <test-suite type="Namespace" name="value" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="1.848" asserts="0">
                        <results>
                          <test-suite type="TestFixture" name="value" executed="True" result="Error" success="False" time="1.570" asserts="0">
                            <failure>
                              <message><![CDATA[SetUp : Svalue]]></message>
                              <stack-trace><![CDATA[value]]></stack-trace>
                            </failure>
                            <results>
                              <test-case name="value" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="0.000" asserts="0">
                                <failure>
                                  <message><![CDATA[value]]></message>
                                  <stack-trace />
                                </failure>
                              </test-case>
                            </results>
                          </test-suite>
                          <test-suite type="ParameterizedFixture" name="Svalue" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="0.008" asserts="0">
                            <results>
                              <test-suite type="TestFixture" name="Svalue" executed="True" result="Error" success="False" time="0.004" asserts="0">
                                <failure>
                                  <message><![CDATA[value]]></message>
                                  <stack-trace><![CDATA[value]]></stack-trace>
                                </failure>
                                <results>
                                  <test-case name="value" executed="True" result="Failure" success="False" time="0.000" asserts="0">
                                    <failure>
                                      <message><![CDATA[value]]></message>
                                      <stack-trace />
                                    </failure>
                                  </test-case>
                                </results>
                              </test-suite>
                            </results>
                          </test-suite>
                        </results>
                      </test-suite>
                    </results>
                  </test-suite>
                </results>
              </test-suite>
            </results>
          </test-suite>
        </results>
      </test-suite>
    </results>
  </test-suite>
</test-results>
```

This is my xml. And this is the xslt I am trying to use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <body>
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <th>Test Method</th>
              <th>Execution Time</th>
              <th>Asserts Performed</th>
              <th>Success</th>
              <th>Result</th>
              <th>Executed</th>
              <th>Failure Message</th>
              <th>ExceptionMessage</th>
              <th>Stack Trace</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="test-results/test-suite">
                <xsl:for-each select="//results/descendant::test-suite[last()]">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="./results/test-case/@name"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="./results/test-case/@time"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="./results/test-case/@asserts"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="./results/test-case/@success"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="./results/test-case/@result"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="./results/test-case/@executed"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="./results/test-case/failure/message/text()" disable-output-escaping="no"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="./failure/message/text()" disable-output-escaping="no"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="./failure/stack-trace/text()" disable-output-escaping="no"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
        </body>
      </html>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, you can see here that nesting of Test-suite/results pair differs in both cases. This way I may have multiple cases. But one thing is certain that tags wont change. And this pattern will be maintained. So, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Can someone please let me know a way to do this? I have already searched a lot for this and still searching side by side.

Comment: You will have more luck getting an answer if you give us the XSLT code you've tried so far as well as the output you want to get. The XPath expression `//ElementB/descendant::ElementC[last()]` will give you the last (that is, the most deeply nested) `<ElementC>` descendant of every `<ElementB>` element, but I'm not sure whether that's what you're actually after.

Comment: let me try this approcah. If it doesn't work out, i'll get you the xml and xslt. Thanks..

Comment: Best practice: Show people a small example of the input AND of the output you want from it. Show them what you've tried. Those, taken together, provide a description of what is it you're actually trying to do and what you might be getting wrong that we can use to generate useful advice. As it stands, your question is not one I can write a useful answer to.

Comment: I tried the approach suggested by Eero. It's working. But the first test case is being skipped.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not quite sure what you're trying to achieve since the input XML file you provided in your edit is quite different in structure from what you had earlier and you didn't post an example of the output you want to get, but maybe you're after something like this?

#### Stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>Test Method</th>
            <th>Execution Time</th>
            <th>Asserts Performed</th>
            <th>Success</th>
            <th>Result</th>
            <th>Executed</th>
            <th>Failure Message</th>
            <th>ExceptionMessage</th>
            <th>Stack Trace</th>
          </tr>

          <!--
          Apply all <test-suite> descendants with a <result> child that has a
          <test-case> child
          -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::test-suite[results/test-case]"/>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test-suite[results/test-case]">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="results/test-case"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="failure"/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test-case">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@name"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@time"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@asserts"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@success"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@result"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@executed"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="failure/message"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test-case/@*">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="failure">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="message | stack-trace"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="message | stack-trace">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Test Method</th>
        <th>Execution Time</th>
        <th>Asserts Performed</th>
        <th>Success</th>
        <th>Result</th>
        <th>Executed</th>
        <th>Failure Message</th>
        <th>ExceptionMessage</th>
        <th>Stack Trace</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>0.000</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>False</td>
        <td>Failure</td>
        <td>True</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>SetUp : Svalue</td>
        <td>value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>0.000</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>False</td>
        <td>Failure</td>
        <td>True</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes..I wanted something like this. But, I have figured out how to do it now. Thanks for the help anyways..